# svn ci vs. svn commit. is there a difference?

Tags: bash, svn

Is there a difference between the two commands:

```
svn ci -m "checking in."
```

and

```
svn commit -m "checking in."
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the command `svn help` lists `commit` as the command with `ci` as the shortcut command. They are equivalent.

```
$ svn help
usage: svn <subcommand> [options] [args]
Subversion command-line client, version 1.8.11.
Type 'svn help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Type 'svn --version' to see the program version and RA modules
  or 'svn --version --quiet' to see just the version number.

Most subcommands take file and/or directory arguments, recursing
on the directories.  If no arguments are supplied to such a
command, it recurses on the current directory (inclusive) by default.

Available subcommands:
   add
   blame (praise, annotate, ann)
   cat
   changelist (cl)
   checkout (co)
   cleanup
   commit (ci)
   copy (cp)
   ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Documentation says that `ci` is just a shortcut for `commit`, so they're equivalent:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html